# Python Pandas String matching from different columns

Tags: python, excel, string, pandas

I have a excel-1(Raw Data) and excel-2(reference Document)

In excel-1 the "Comments" should be matched against excel-2 "Comments" column.If the string in excel-1 "comments" column contains any of the substring in excel-2 "comments" column,the Primary reason and Secondary reason from excel-2 should be populated against each row in excel-1.

Excel-1
{'Item': {0: 'rr-1', 1: 'ss-2'}, 'Order': {0: 1, 1: 2}, 'Comments': {0: 'Good;Stock out of order,#1237-MF, Closing the stock ', 1: 'no change, bad, next week delivery,09/12/2018-MF*'}}

Excel-2
{'Comments': {0: 'Good', 1: 'Stock out of order', 2: 'Stock closed ', 3: 'No Change', 4: 'Bad stock', 5: 'Next week delivery '}, 'Primary Reason': {0: 'Quality', 1: 'Warehouse', 2: 'Logistics ', 3: 'Feedback', 4: 'Warehouse', 5: 'Logistics '}, 'Secondary Reason': {0: 'Manufacture', 1: 'Stock', 2: 'Warehouse', 3: 'Feedback', 4: 'Stock', 5: 'Warehouse'}}

Please help to build the logic.

I get the answer when there is single match  using pd.dataframe.str.contains/isin  function but how to write the logic to search multiple matches and to write in a particular structure format.

[image: desired output picture]

```
for value in df['Comments']:
    string = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!|,|;]',r'',value)
    for index,value in df1.iterrows():
        substring = df1.Comment[index]
        if substring in string:
            df['Primary Reason']= df1['Primary Reason'][index]
            df['Secondary Reason']=df1['Secondary Reason'][index]
```

Comment: have you somehow solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

for value in df['Comments']:

```
string = re.sub(r'[?|$|.|!|,|;]',r'',value)

for index,value in df1.iterrows():

    substring = df1.Comment[index]

    if substring in string:

        df['Primary Reason']= df1['Primary Reason'][index]

        df['Secondary Reason']=df1['Secondary Reason'][index]
```

## Analysis from above code:

1. Basically you are comparing row1 of excel-1 and row-1 of excel-2 and matching the substring and string and getting Primary and Secondary Reason right  ?
2. Here you are **overwriting the same location** i.e o/p location and because of this reason you always end up with only 1 result.

Issue is in the following code:

```
df['Primary Reason']= df1['Primary Reason'][index]

df['Secondary Reason']=df1['Secondary Reason'][index]
```

3. Come up with the logic where you can add up result in the same line as below format

   res1, res2 ....etc